# Putting Variable with in single quotes?

Tags: ruby, json, api

Hi all I am making a request to the Campaign Monitor API and the data has to be held with in single quotes as a string but in JSON format. As it has to be single quotes I am unable to put in any variable values. Below is the code.

```
response = HTTParty.post(url, 
:basic_auth => auth, :body => '{
            "EmailAddress":"js@mike.com",
            "Name":"#{@fname}",
            "CustomFields":[
                  {
                            "Key":"firstName",
                            "Value":"#{@fname}"
                        },
                        {
                          "Key":"country",
                            "Value":"#{@country}"
                        }
                        ],
            "Resubscribe":true,
            "RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders":true
        }')
```

I have tried a few different methods such as breaking the string up and piecing it back together with the variable with in double quotes but that has failed as well for the request to be successful it has to be exact.

Comment: This makes no sense at all. A string is a string, it doesn't matter whether it was defined as a single-quoted string literal, a double-quoted string literal, heredoc, or a pink magic unicorn. There is simply no way for the `HTTParty::post` method to even distinguish between single and double quotes, that's just syntax for the string literal and doesn't even survive the parsing process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try with [heredoc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Ruby) :

```
response = HTTParty.post(url, 
  :basic_auth => auth, :body => <<-BODY_CONTENT
  {
        "EmailAddress":"js@mike.com",
        "Name":"#{@fname}",
        "CustomFields":[
              {
                        "Key":"firstName",
                        "Value":"#{@fname}"
                    },
                    {
                      "Key":"country",
                        "Value":"#{@country}"
                    }
                    ],
        "Resubscribe":true,
        "RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders":true
  }
BODY_CONTENT
)
```

Comment: Awesome that works perfectly :) Would you mind explaining how that concept works I have never seen that before. Thanks again :)

Comment: It is just syntax that allows multiline strings content. It works like double quote (you can add variable values) but the beginning of the string content is defined by `<<[KEYWORD]`, and the end will occure with a line that only contains the `[KEYWORD]`. The link I gave you in the answer describes perfectly the syntax and all the opportunities heredoc givs you.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of building a JSON structure by hand, you can build a Ruby hash and convert it to JSON:

```
require 'json'

data = {
  'EmailAddress' => 'js@mike.com',
  'Name' => @fname,
  'CustomFields' => [
    { 'Key' => 'firstName', 'Value' => @fname },
    { 'Key' => 'country', 'Value' => @country }
  ],
  'Resubscribe' => true,
  'RestartSubscriptionBasedAutoresponders' => true
}

response = HTTParty.post(url, basic_auth: auth, body: data.to_json)
```

Also note that there's a Ruby gem for the Campaign Monitor API: [createsend-ruby](http://campaignmonitor.github.io/createsend-ruby/)

Using the gem, the above code translates to:

```
custom_fields = [
  { 'Key' => 'firstName', 'Value' => @fname },
  { 'Key' => 'country', 'Value' => @country }
]
response = CreateSend::Subscriber.add(auth, list_id, 'js@mike.com', @fname, custom_fields, true, true)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use heredoc as explained [here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Here_documents)

> Double-quoting rules are also followed if you put double quotes around
>   the identifier. However, do not put double quotes around the
>   terminator.

```
puts <<"QUIZ"
Student: #{name}

1.\tQuestion: What is 4+5?
\tAnswer: The sum of 4 and 5 is #{4+5}
QUIZ
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use here documents:

```
name = 'John'
<<EOS
This is #{name}
EOS
```

Alternatively you can use flexible quotes, they can handle both `'` and `"` characters:

```
name = 'John'
%{
This is #{name}
}
```

Flexible quoting works with `%()` and `%!!` as well.